# How to merge the elements of nested list with changing inside elements?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a nested list. Two of inside elements can be a same, one is different. I need to change that list in some way that better to demonstrate.

```
before = [['a','a', 1],['a','a', 2], ['a','b', 6], ['a','b', 0], ['a','c',5]
#after some changes
after = [['a','a', 3], ['a','b', 6], ['a','c',5]]
```

So i need to summarize the "i[2] elements for i in before" if i[0],i[1] are same. That formulation is already looking like comprehension, but i see no ways to do it in this way.

I did it like that. But i sure it's not most elegant solution.

```
before = [['a','a', 1],['a','a', 2], ['a','b', 6], ['a','b', 0], ['a','c',5]]
#creating a list of unique combinations, actually it's already created and used for another aims too
after = set([(i[0],i[1],0) for i in before])
after = [list(i) for i in after]
# output is [['a', 'c', 0], ['a', 'b', 0], ['a', 'a', 0]]

for k,i in enumerate(after):
    #starting the loop from list of uniq_combinations
    q = 0 #for element we need to summarize, reseting var for each iteration
    for j in before:
            if (i[0],i[1]) == (j[0],j[1]):
                q = j[2] #the third element for each nested list
                after[k][2] +=q #summarizing the result while looking for same combination
print(after)
#output have correct result [['a', 'a', 3], ['a', 'b', 6], ['a', 'c', 5]]
```

I've looked in itertools lib, but can't find suitable method

Comment: @Unmitigated , @Pranav Hosangadi, @Jorge Luis
Thanks for your answers!

As i understood all solutions is based on dict or dict-like types. I maked some simple speed tests for each way. That is result for 1kk iterations:
`my_var 0:00:07.599 
group_by 0:00:04.533 
default_dict 0:00:04.433 
dict_simple 0:00:03.800 
dict_counter 0:00:10.016`

As you see the fastest way to use a dict, as @Pranav Hosangadi recommended. But i have preferred to use defaultdict, because the difference is not to big, and code is shorter.

It's curious what using `counter()` took more time even than my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`, as long as elements with the same key are always adjacent.

```py
from itertools import groupby
l = [['a','a', 1],['a','a', 2], ['a','b', 6], ['a','b', 0], ['a','c',5]]
res = [[*k, sum(o[2] for o in g)] for k, g in groupby(l, lambda o:o[:2])]
```

A `defaultdict` can also be used to store the sum for each key.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for *k, v in l: d[tuple(k)] += v
res = [[*k, v] for k, v in d.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the current count for each pair of characters in a dictionary. As you iterate over the `item`s in the `before` list, retrieve the value at `item[0:2]` in the dictionary, and add `item[2]` to this value.

```
result = {}
for item in before:
    # Convert item[0:2] to tuple because dict keys need to be immutable
    key = tuple(item[0:2]) 

    # Get value in result at key (or zero if it doesn't exist)
    # Then add item[2] to it
    # Then assign it back to result[key]
    result[key] = result.get(key, 0) + item[2]
```

This gives `result` as:

```
{('a', 'a'): 3, ('a', 'b'): 6, ('a', 'c'): 5}
```

Now, simply iterate over the keys and values of `result` and create your `after` list:

```
after = [[*key, val] for key, val in result.items()]
```

which gives:

```
[['a', 'a', 3], ['a', 'b', 6], ['a', 'c', 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same approach that [Pranav Hosangadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843953) uses.

We iterate the list and make a dictionary whose keys are the first two elements as a tuple and the value is the sum of the third coordinate.
We don't have to make the addition manually: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) can do it for us:

```
from collections import Counter

before_counter = Counter()
for triad in before:
    # Tuple as a key, third element as the quantity
    before_counter.update({(triad[0], triad[1]) : triad[2]})
```

Then just convert it into the desired list:

```
after = [[*pair, count] for pair, count in before_counter.items()]
```